# Find pattern mulifasta list based on user input in Perl

Tags: perl, design-patterns, fasta

I am trying to fix a Perl code. Given the following "file.txt":

```
>otu1  
AACGCCTTTCCNGGATGGCAAAATTTNTNGTAAA
AGGGCACCCANTTCTGGCTCGAAA  
>otu2
NNAATCGGNNNGGGGCGTAANGAGGTTNCGGCACGG
TNCCCGTTTANCG
>otu3   
CTGGNATAAAAAANNNNTACTTAA
```

After providing a otu number as argument (i.e. otu2) when calling the program, 
I want to first (1) check if that otu is present in the file.txt, 
then (2) find the pattern [NC].[CT] (element N or C, followed by any element . and followed by an element C or T) within the otu sequence, and finally
(3) print out the start‐ and end‐position of every site.

For the first two questions I am trying with the following code but I am encountering problems by integrating subroutines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

$otu = $ARGV[0];   
check_otu("file.txt");

sub check_otu {
    my $content = shift;
    open(my $fh, '<' , $content) || die "File not found: $!";
    my $content;    

    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        if ( $line =~ /^>/ ) {
            check_pattern($content) if $content=$otu;
            $content = $line;
        }
        else {
            $content .= $line;
        }
    }
    check_motifs($content);
}

}
sub check_pattern{
    my $fasta = $content;
    $count++ if count_pattern($fasta);
}
sub count_pattern {
    my $chain = $content;
    my @all = $chain =~ /([NC].[CT])/g;
    scalar @all;
}
```

I got these errors:

```
"my" variable $content masks earlier declaration in same scope at proof.pl line 12.
Name "main::count" used only once: possible typo at proof.pl line 28.
Undefined subroutine &main::check_motifs called at proof.pl line 23, <$fh> line 8.
```

Would you have any suggestion? Any hint for the third question?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of problems are you encountering? Are there error messages? Does it do something else than what you expect? Please be more specific. You can [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: In the line `check_pattern($content) if $content=$otu;` you are _assigning_ `$otu` to `$content`. That is always true (unless `$otu` is `undef`, `""` or `0`) and changes the value of `$content`.

Comment: you didnt declared the variable `$filename` in the following code:  `sub check_otu {
    my $content = shift;
    open(my $fh, '<' , $filename) || die "File not found: $!";`
you may change it to `open(my $fh, '<' , $content)`, because `$content` is actually `"file.txt"`

Comment: in line : check_pattern($content) if $content=$otu , I am attempting to check if input name $otu is found in the file $content

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain shortly what is a "motif" and a "cite" is to help others that are not familiar with bioinformatics.

Comment: Using a fasta reader module like the one in bioperl would make the first part really easy (And there's probably something in bioperl for the second part too)

Comment: the expression motifs is here similar to pattern, that means a specific combination of letters ordered in a sequence. Now the term is replaced in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bioperl [makes it easy](https://bioperl.org/howtos/SeqIO_HOWTO.html) to read fasta files. Use it instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

The special variables `@-` and `@+` hold the indexes of the start and end of the last matched pattern (And any capturing groups inside it). You'll need that for your third bit.

You might end up with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my ($file, $otu) = @ARGV;
my $fasta = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $file, -format => 'fasta');
my $found = 0;

while (my $seq = $fasta->next_seq()) {
  next unless $seq->primary_id() eq $otu;
  $found = 1;
  my $s = $seq->seq();
  while ($s =~ m/[NC].[CT]/g) {
    my $start = $-[0];
    my $stop = $+[0] - 1; # Index in this array is 1 past the last character
    say "$start $stop";
  }
}

say "$otu not found" unless $found;
```

Example:

```
$ perl otu.pl sample.fasta otu2
15 17
31 33
37 39
40 42
```